# Number of directed graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Hi i have to find the number of directed graphs with vertices labelled {${1... n}$}

My idea: For each vertex we can put $n$ ($n-1$ other vertices $+1$ itself) possible edges. So it would be something like $n*2^n$ possible directed graphs.

Is my idea correct. How can i improve it ?

Comment: Well, we have here three different answers. You should specify: **(1)** if an arrow from $x$ to $y$ excludes an arrow from $y$ to $x$ and **(2)** if arrows from an element to itself are allowed.

Comment: No an arrow from x to y doesnt exclude an arrow from y to x. And yes arrows can go to the elements themself.

Comment: Then I think that the first ml0105's answer and mine is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A directed graph can be viewed as a relation. Given a fixed vertex set, the edge set $E \subset [n] \times [n]$, where $[n] = \{1, \ldots, n\}$. The possible subsets of $[n] \times [n]$ are contained contained in the power set $2^{[n] \times [n]}$. So there are $2^{n^{2}}$ possible directed graphs.

**Note:** My solution allows for loops. If you exclude loops, then you are looking at subsets of $([n] \times [n]) \setminus \{ (i, i) : i \in [n] \}$, which has cardinality $n^{2} - n$. So without loops, there would be $2^{n^{2}-n}$ possible digraphs.

**Edit:** A small critique of your solution. Each vertex has $2^{n}$ possible edges incident to it. You are determining the digraph by the neighborhood of each vertex. So you have:

$$N(v_{1}) \cup N(v_{2}) \cup \ldots \cup N(v_{n})$$

Where $N(v_{i}) \cap N(v_{j}) = \emptyset$ for distinct $i, j$. For each $i \in [n]$, $N(v_{i}) \in 2^{[n]}$, so there are $2^{n}$ possible options for each $v_{i}$. Hence, there are $(2^{n})^{n} = 2^{n^{2}}$ possible digraphs.

Comment: Oh thank you, now i understood my mistake

Answer (score 2):

For every pair $u,v\;$of vertices, there's either

- Only an edge from $u\;$to $v$.$\\[4pt]$

  Only an edge from $v\;$to $u$.$\\[4pt]$

  Both.$\\[4pt]$

  Neither.

So $4$ choices for each pair of vertices.

Since there are $\binom{n}{2}$ pairs of vertices, there are 
$$4^{\binom{n}{2}} = 2^{n^2-n}$$
 directed graphs on a given set of $n$ vertices.

I'm assuming no multiple edges with the same source and target, and no loops.

If loops are allowed, then for each loopless directed graph, there are $2^n$ ways of defining loops (since each of the $2^n$ subsets of the set of $n$ vertices could be the subset having loops). Thus, the new count would be
$$(2^n)\bigl(2^{n^2-n}\bigr)=2^{n^2}$$
As regards your error . . .

As you noted, allowing loops, each vertex has $2^n$ choices for edges originating from that vertex.

Since there are $n$ vertices, the multiplication rule yields a count of $(2^n)^n = 2^{n^2}\!\!,\;$not $n2^n$.

In other words, there should be $n\;$*factors*, each equal to $2^n,\;$rather than $n$ summands, each equal to $2^n$.

Comment: What is wrong with my solution ?

Comment: Try it for some small values of $n$.

Comment: Sorry there can be loops.

Comment: Ok, I edited in the adjustment for loops.

Comment: A useful question, which prompted various approaches.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that for every ordered pair of vertices $(x,y)$ ($x$ and $y$ may be equal or different) there can be, or not be, an arrow from $x$ to $y$.

Then, there are $n^2$ possible arrows. The number of graphs is, hence, the number of subsets of the set of all possible arrows, that is, $2^{n^2}$.