# number of simple digraphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I read a question on the internet related to the number of simple digraphs, which said that the number of simple digraphs with $|V|=3$ is $2^9$.

However, I remembered the number of them is actually $2^{n(n-1)}=2^{6}$

Can anyone please verify for me? I would be grateful.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2573784/number-of-directed-graphs

Answer (score 1):

If you allow arrows from a vertex to itself, then the formula is $2^{n^2}$. But I see in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph#Types_of_directed_graphs) that simple digraphs don't allow this kind of arrows. In this case the formula is $2^{n(n-1)}$.